# Twitter Bootstrap missing responsive classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot for the life of me find the following classes which are mentioned from the following link: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

The classes in question are these:

- `.visible-xs-*`
- `.visible-sm-*`
- `.visible-md-*`
- `.visible-lg-*`

They are not within the `bootstrap.css` file.

---

***Update***

Extract of the Bootstrap css file of the version information. I hope it helps narrow things down.

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.2 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

/*! normalize.css v3.0.2 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */
```

---

***Update 2***

I just wanted to make sure I'm using the above classes correctly.

```
<div class="visible-xs-*">This should show on phones only</div>
```

Is this the correct way in doing it or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot find"?

Comment: I just updated the question to include the bit of info. I could not find it within the bootstrap.css file

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the right place?

Comment: Look in here https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css at line 6359.

Comment: Hey DavidG thank you so much for your really quick replies. I've updated the question to include the bootstrap css version info

Comment: I linked to that version, it's in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remember * at here will be 1 of this:

```
block
inline
inline-block
```

> As of v3.2.0, the `.visible-*-*` classes for each breakpoint come in
>   three variations, one for each CSS display property value listed
>   below.

```
Group of classes             CSS display
.visible-*-block             display: block;
.visible-*-inline            display: inline;
.visible-*-inline-block      display: inline-block;
```

example: `.visible-xs-block`, `.visible-xs-inline`, `.visible-xs-inline-block`. see more in table **Group of classes** http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood how it was meant to be used. Thank you very much for this :)